# Android Studio Bug Says new Is Unresolved Reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am trying to make an app for my friends and this error wont go away. I need to finish the app before march 6th and am not going to make it if i don't fix this error and finish the rest. Also, If there is a way to make nav_view into not a specific nav_ but every nav_ there is. So i can jump from nav_donate to nav_prayers or nav_donate to nav_events.

errors are at the bottom of the page

```
package com.naifcenter.mohammad.naifcenter

import android.app.FragmentManager
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home_page.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.app_bar_home_page.*

class HomePage : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }

        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.home_page, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> return true
            else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.nav_prayer_rug -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                        ,new prayertime())
                        .commit()  

            }
            R.id.nav_calendar -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new calendar())
                        .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_donate -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new donate())
                        .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_projects -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new projects())
                        .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_social_media -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new socialmedia ())
                        .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_bugs -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new bugs())
                        .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_share -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new share())
                        .commit()
            }
            R.id.nav_send -> {
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.nav_view
                                ,new contact())
                        .commit()
            }
        }

        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        return true
    }
}
```

current error is 
Classifier 'FragmentManager' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here
(line 61)

Unresolved reference: new
(line 66, 74, 80, 86, 92, 98, 104, 110)

Comment: Looks like you're using Kotlin, you should remove the `new` keyword. Also since you are using `AppCompatActivity` use `val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager`

Comment: Im testing that now

Comment: Type mismatch: inferred type is prayertime but Fragment! was expected

Comment: Your classes `prayertime`, `calendar`, etc must extend `Fragment`

Comment: Unresolved reference: contactFragment

Answer (score 0):

you are pretty much mixing java and kotlin and this is causing some syntax related erros.

if you want to replace a fragment just do something like this in kotlin
define this function at in your activity

```
 fun FragmentManager.replaceFragment(containerId: Int, fragment: Fragment) {
    beginTransaction().replace(containerId, fragment).commit()
}
```

now you can call this extension function to replace fragment from anywhere

```
fragmentManager.replaceFragment(R.id.flContainer, PrayerTime())
```

Comment: I will try it as soon as i get sdk to launch